# C# Depency Injected ILogger should be static or not?

Tags: dependency-injection, static, ilogger

I saw some senior developers write codes like:

```
  public class QuotationController : ControllerBase
    {
        private static ILogger _logger;

        public QuotationController(ILogger logger)
        {
            _logger = logger.ForContext<QuotationController>();
        }
}
```

and We are using Serilog for logging

```
void RegisterLogging(WebApplicationBuilder appBuilder)
{
    var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables("VAL_")
        .Build();
    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .ReadFrom.Configuration(config)
        .CreateLogger();

    appBuilder.Host.UseSerilog(Log.Logger);
}
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
RegisterLogging(builder);
```

Is `private static ILogger _logger;` a good practice?

Will replacing it with `private Readonly ILogger _logger;` be better?

Comment: Why don't you ask those senior developers why they are doing that?